# Injecting into supertype dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, koin

Is it possible to inject into supertypes in Dagger 2?

if I have a property like this

```
@Inject
Wallet<Material>
```

Would the following provide work ?

```
@Provides
Wallet<LeatherMaterial> provide()
{
return new Wallet<LeatherMaterial>
}
```

Actually I should have rephrased the question . It isn't working and I get an error that demands an injection of the exact  Wallet

do we have any workarounds ? . does koin provide some functionality like this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to be explicit. Add the following to your Module, if you already have `Wallet<LeatherMaterial>` in your dependency graph somewhere:

```
@Binds abstract Wallet<Material> provide(Wallet<LeatherMaterial> leatherWaller);
```

Otherwise, go with:

```
@Provides static Wallet<Material> provide() {
    return new Wallet<LeatherMaterial>(){ /* ... */ };
}
```

**Edit:**
Revisiting this answer because it occured to me the solutions I've provided wont work due to how generics are treated in Java. Instead, you would need to use:

`Wallet<? extends Material>` in place of `Wallet<Material>` in my above answers, and do the same wherever it is injected as well.

Comment: Great. I'll test this out in a moment